# how to auto update Service References in window phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have add Service References in my app. References Service is always changing, so I want auto update References Services  when in server is update ?

How to update ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. As with any other type of project, Visual Studio will generate the proxy classes when you create the service reference or when you manually update it by right clicking it and selecting "Update Service Reference".

Comment: other way not to call services alfonso ? Beascause my services is always changing ? if i update to MarketPlace , how to update app in marketPlace ? Please help me !

Comment: You will have to be careful on how you update your services to ensure backward compatibility. You might be interested in [REST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529) services and [OData](http://www.odata.org/) if you are looking for a bit more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility would be to built up proxy classes dynamically everytime you run the app. An example of an applications that does this is the OData Explorer available here http://www.odata.org/developers/odata-sdk including source.

Good luck!